# How to hide datatypes displaying as json values of @RequestBody example value in swagger-ui?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, openapi

My Spring Boot app has a model class `ReqGetActive` used as request model in  a `@PostMapping` request body.

Controller:

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/api/getActive",
        consumes = "application/JSON",
        produces = "application/JSON")
public ResponseEntity<String> getActive(
        @ApiParam(value = "Consumer's request body", required = true)
        @RequestBody ReqGetActive jsonPojo) throws Exception {
    return null;
}
```

ReqGetActive:

```java
import lombok.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;

public class ReqGetActive {
    @JsonProperty("RequestData")
    @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
    private RequestData RequestData;

    @Getter @Setter @ToString
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    private static class RequestData{
        @JsonProperty("ReportTitle")
        @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_CASE_INSENSITIVE_PROPERTIES)
        private String ReportTitle;
    }
}
```

It displays the request model in swagger-ui like: 
[swagger-ui-screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg9iZ.png)

Now my doubt is, as you see in the above picture **the datatypes of class ReqGetActive fields are displayed as values of json fields.**

Is it possible to display only the keys and the values as `""` in the json model?

P.s: I use just swagger annotations to display in swagger-ui

Comment: I have solved it using @ApiModelProperty to change it to my desired value.  @ApiModelProperty(example = "[ExampleTitle]") private String ReportTitle;

Comment: if you have solved your own problem, then please [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have manged to set required value using @ApiModelProperty to change it to my desired value. @ApiModelProperty(example = "[ExampleTitle]") private String ReportTitle;

ie., I can set any values except " " or null

Refer here: 
https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1473

[Ans Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECL2H.png)